# How do I list all lines after two subsequent patterns are matched up to when they don't

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have files that are used to install files with specific owner:group and permissions.  I'll ignore permissions for clarity and the details of installing files.  Once an owner & group are set to a specific pair, then I want to print a separator line followed by all subsequent lines until either the owner or group changes.  If I could print the line numbers with the lines, that would be great too.  The pair I'm searching for is owner, group as ownerX, groupY respectively.

Example (I don't need line numbers, so I'll leave them off)

```
type = d  
owner = root  
group = staff  
    mode = 0750 <-Ignore.  owner & group aren't ownerX & groupY  
    ...  <- Ignore  
group = groupY <- owner=root, not ownerX, so still not ownerX & groupY  
    ...  <- Ignore  
owner = ownerX <-Now, owner=ownerX and group=groupY  
    <- Print -----------------  
    mode = 0750             <- Print  
    target = /app_dir/conf  <- Print   
    target = /app_dir/data  <- Print  
owner = dilbert          <- Stop printing since not ownerX & groupY  
    ...  <- Ignore  
group = Dogbert  
    ...  <- Ignore  
group = groupY  
    ...  <- Ignore  
owner = ownerX  
    <- Print a separator line  
    type = f                                                       <- Print  
    mode = 0540                                                    <- Print  
    source = [path to compiled binary file in source environment]/file1_ver2  <- Print  
    target = [path to a bin directory in the install environment]/file  <- Print  
owner = oracle <- stop printing  
...  
<End of File, EOF>
```

So, the desired output would be:

```
---------  
mode = 0750  
target = /app_dir/conf  
target = /app_dir/data  
---------  
type = f  
mode = 0540  
source = [path to compiled binary file in source environment]/file1_ver2  
target = [path to a bin directory in the install environment]/file1
```

---

That would help me apply the following fixes:
Change the 1st mode from 0750 (group is read-only) to 0770.
Change the 2nd mode from 0540 (group can't execute) to 0550.

Comment: Is there a way to maintain the carriage returns in the posts I write?  My post looks aweful without \n separators.

Comment: tony, two spaces at the end of the line for CR, four spaces at the beginning to indent a line of code

Comment: Could you post a little example of file you have in input and the output you are expecting? (like 10 lines per file)

Comment: Rui,  thanks for the formatting tips, and it looks like you were able to edit it for me cause it looks good now.  Double thanks!

Comment: Purplepsycho, I'll try to give an example, but hitting Enter in the comment box seems to send the comment.  I'll try editing the original example.  The problem is associated with gues files and Solaris Package installs that my program uses to create our own custom packages that we install.  I don't know the background, but only how we use them on my job.  ... (cont'd)

Comment: ... (cont'd) I won't go further into the packaging process, but there are very many gues files of the format I showed above and I'm looking for groups of lines where it creates a directory or installs a file whose owner:group permissions are ownerX:groupY [d or -]<owner perms><group perms><other perms>.  If the <group perms> are more restrictive than the <owner perms>, then I must modify the <group perms> in the gues file. ... (cont'd)

Comment: ... (cont'd) This is related to a post I made several days ago titled "Find files with group permissions more restrictive than owner permissions ".  That found "created" directories and "installed" files that had problems.  This post is to help find the source of the those files and fix them so that the <group permissions> are not more restrictive than their <owner permissions>.  Then the next time the custom packages are installed, the directories and files will have owner and group permissions that are identical.  Now I'll edit my example above.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk` with two flags e.g.:

```
awk '/group =/{a=0};/group = groupY/{$0="----------";a=1}
/owner =/{b=0};/owner = ownerX/{$0="----------";b=1};a*b' infile
```

so it would only print when both are 1/true. If you wanted to print only the lines matching `mode` along with their line numbers you could add another condition:

```
awk '/group =/{a=0};/group = groupY/{$0="------------";a=1};/owner =/{b=0}
/owner = ownerX/{$0="------------";b=1};(($1=="mode") && (a*b==1)){print NR, $0}' infile
```

Comment: Note that this solution assumes `owner = ownerX` and  `group = groupY` never occur on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

don_crissti, thanks!  That got me very close.  It worked if the file starts with:

```
group = groupY
owner = ownerX
```

But it missed if the owner came 1st:
    owner = ownerX
    group = groupY

Using your solution and finding an online awk tutorial, I modified it to capture both cases.  While I didn't originally request this, I'm only interested in the mode settings.  So instead of printing all lines within a range, I'm printing only lines that contain mode.  Problem solved:

```
awk '/group =/{t=0}
/group = groupY/{t=1}
/owner =/{p=0}
{if ((t==1) && (p==1) && (seperator_printed==0)) {
  print "-------------------------"
  seperator_printed=1
  }
}
{if ((t==1) && (p==1)) {
    if ($0 ~ /mode/) {print NR, $0}
  } else {
    separator_printed=0
  }
}' infile
```

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question. Answer updated.